# Error:OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

Tags: php, api, ssl, curl, openssl

While I try calling PHP APIs from local machine it is working without any exception, however when I try the same from my cloud server I am getting below error.

OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104

Your suggestion or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide the output of `curl -v` for both cases so that one can see what to expect and where exactly it breaks.